# I'm having an issue getting the second single quote to show up in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm working with SQL and C# so I need my string to show up verbatim to what I've type into them. For what I am working on the string needs to say

- `Select* from dbo.tblIndiviualFoods where foodName = 'food'`

but when I debug the sting it comes out as

- `Select* from dbo.tblIndiviualFoods where foodName = 'food`

here's what my code looks like I'm not quite sure what's wrong

```
string commandString = string.Format("Select* from dbo.tblIndiviualFoods where foodName = '{0}'", currentIngredentFromList);
```

Comment: Can't reproduce - https://dotnetfiddle.net/qlHxXt

Comment: You say _when I debug the string_ - how are you debugging it? Incidentally I suspect SQL will want a space between the `SELECT` and the `*`

Comment: Also, as a matter of style - prefixing the table name with `tbl` is very old-fashioned - and not ideal as [one day it might be a view, after all](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/is-adding-the-tbl-prefix-to-table-names-really-a-problem) - and there's a spelling mistake - it should be 'Indivi**d**ualFoods'

Comment: This is also a recipe for a SQL injection attack. Don't build SQL statements as a string like this. Use parameters properly.

Comment: @stuartd believe it or not, [DBs don't care](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/avjzdRB1zTMFxrce3ytUzA/0) about spaces around *

Comment: Amen to Enigmativity's words. See http://Bobby-tables.com